# android WebView use localStorage like webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.token='something'");

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I already do

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8); String appCachePath = activity.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();    webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);     webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

how can I set local Storage through loadUrl method?

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('haha')");
```

this can work

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.token='something'");
```

How can I make this work? It looks as there have no local Storage variable.